# A word for someone who is out of touch

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

During a recent conversation with one of my friends, whom I had not been regularly speaking to, I asked her whether her sister had applied for a job as I knew she’d graduated some months ago. She told me that it’s been almost two months since her sister started working, mildly surprised at my unawareness. ‘Out of touch’ is the expression she used. On searching for its meaning, I found that it can either mean ‘not in contact with someone and hence unaware of their life events’ or ‘unaware of current major events/trends in important areas of modern life’. I want to know any word or words that can be used to describe a person’s state of being out of touch in each of the senses.
Thank you beforehand.

Comment: "Out of touch" can be used to describe a person's state of being out of touch in both the senses.

Comment: You already used the word [**unaware**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unaware). Also [**uninformed**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/uninformed). Oh! the question has been changed.

Comment: "It's been so long...."

Comment: The 50 cent term is **incommunicado** https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incommunicado You've been incommunicado for months.

Answer (score 2):

The word Detatched comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions that come immediately to mind; I'm sure there are others:

**not in contact with someone and hence unaware of their life events**

detached, distant, unfamiliar, absent, disconnected, remote, unavailable

**unaware of current major events/trends in important areas of modern life**

detached, buried, isolated, monastic, cloistered, secluded, sequestered

Comment: oh, sorry, i see what you’re doing